# Why is there a 0...1 Relation with join table?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, relationship, joincolumn

can anyone help me to understand why in this graphic this relation is 0...1.
When I try to delete 'profile' Heidi Sql says there is a FK violation.
Logical it is fine, but I want to understand how this works.
There can be no 'wellbeeing' without a 'profile', but why is this relation there.
So in my opinion this must be a 1 --- 0...*

The diagram is created with intelliJ and I use this code.

> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
> @JoinTable(name = "profile_chronicMedication", joinColumns =
> {@JoinColumn(name = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name =
> "chronic_medication_id")})    private Set
> chronicMedications = new HashSet<>();

[image]

EDIT: Also it is possible for IntelliJ to recogize this type of relation. What I need to change for the relation with a join table? Is this really not possible or at least show the join tables as well?

Class Role:

> @ManyToOne(optional = false)
>
> private Profile profile;

Class Profile:

> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile")
>
> private Set roles = new HashSet<>();

[image]

Comment: Nothing guarantees that every profile is associated to a wellbeing. So it's a 0..1 cardinality. You can code the app to make sure that never happens, but IntelliJ can't guess that.

Comment: But why i can not delete profiles as long as there are wellbeeings? Heidi does know about, why intellij not?

Maybe it is possible to delete the keys in the join table and so there exist a weelbeeing without a profile?

But thats not define that acutal function of the app. Which diagram will suit my needs better?